# C# TCP connection to SMTP relay. Chinese encoding

Tags: c#, email, encoding, smtp

I wrote a C# program, which connects to a local SMTP relay to send emails. It observes a directory for EML files and sends them to the SMTP relay. Important for me is, that the emails are sent without any modifications.
The program works as expected, but it has problems with Chinese encodings. I don't know where to search for the issue - is it my program or the relay?

Here is an example what i want to send (Content of the EML file):
[image]

And that is what i receive when I send it:
[image]

I thought i should not have any trouble with the encoding, because I am reading the file **as it is** and read it binary, so it should be an exact copy.

Have a look at my code, maybe you can find any issues:

```
using (var client = new TcpClient())
        {

            client.ReceiveTimeout = 500;
            client.Connect(endPt);

            using (var stream = client.GetStream())
            {
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream) { AutoFlush = true })
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {

                    //Some boring authentification, not shown here ...

                    sendData(writer, reader, "DATA", false, DELAY_COMMANDS);

                    sendDataBinary(writer, reader, info.BinaryContent, false, DELAY_COMMANDS);

                    sendData(writer, reader, "", false, DELAY_COMMANDS);
                    sendData(writer, reader, "\n", false, DELAY_COMMANDS);
                    sendData(writer, reader, "\n", false, DELAY_COMMANDS);
                    sendData(writer, reader, "\n", false, DELAY_COMMANDS);
                    sendData(writer, reader, "\n", false, DELAY_COMMANDS);

                    sendData(writer, reader, ".", false, DELAY_COMMANDS);
                    sendData(writer, reader, "QUIT", false, DELAY_COMMANDS);


                    Console.Write("End of mail sending..");
                }
                client.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    static void sendDataBinary(StreamWriter writer, StreamReader reader, byte[] data, bool bBase64 = false, int iWait = 0)
    {
        writer.BaseStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        writer.WriteLine();

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(iWait);

        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
    }

    static void sendData(StreamWriter writer, StreamReader reader, string data, bool bBase64 = false, int iWait = 0)
    {
        if (bBase64)
            writer.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)));
        else
            writer.WriteLine(data);


        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(iWait);

        Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadLine());
    }
```

Maybe anybody of you can help me, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using one of the StreamWriter constructor overloads and specify an encoding like UTF8

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, that did not help. I have no clue how to convert the different charsets.

Part of the email:
`X-Mailer: Microsoft Outlook Express 5.50.4522.1200
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="SHIFT_JIS"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

ƒRƒR‚Ìƒgƒbƒv‚ÉƒAƒhƒŒƒX‚â“d˜b”Ô†‚È‚Ç‚ðÚ‚¹‚Ä‚¢‚Ü‚·B`

No matter what encoding I am using, i always get trash. I am trying to convert it with: 
`System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("shift_jis")`, but it is always only trash. Any suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not all SMTP servers can handle binary data, and even the ones that do require that you specify that you'll be sending it in the `MAIL FROM` command.

You also need to "byte-stuff" the message content in case any lines begin with a '.' which you are not doing. While you may not have run into any issues yet, you are asking for problems by not doing things properly.

For these reasons, I'd recommend that you use my [MimeKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit) and [MailKit](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit) libraries for this.

MimeKit is a very robust MIME parser that you can use to load email messages from disk (or any stream) and MailKit implements an SmtpClient that is capable of sending those parsed messages.